# How to make an Aurora instance reachable over the internet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc, amazon-aurora

I have a staging and a production EKS cluster on AWS, and they use different DBs.

**I need to deploy a replica of the prod app deployment in a temp namespace inside the staging cluster.**

Now, the temp deployment needs to be connected to the prod Aurora.

But, the staging and production clusters are in separate VPCs, but [unfortunately] with the same CIDRs. So I cannot peer the two VPCs.

Also, the Aurora cluster is deployed in private subnets.

One [temporary] solution that I am thinking of is, to essentially make public the private subnet the Aurora writer is deployed into, and have my app in the staging cluster reach the prod db over the internet.

1. I found the private subnet that the Aurora writer is deployed into
2. Found the routing table that it uses
3. Could I just change the routing rule from `0.0.0.0/0 -> NAT-12345` to `0.0.0.0/0 -> IGW-12345` so instead of NAT it will use the Internet Gateway?

Is this something viable, and if so, do I need to make something else in order for the db endpoint `eg the-prod-aurora-postgres.cluster-something123.uk-west-45.rds.amazonaws.com` to be reachable over the internet?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aurora-private-public-endpoints/

Comment: I guess first you need to make the subnet public as you describe, and then follow the instructions of the link above.

Comment: Once the subnet becomes public the securitry group the SG of the database will have to be adjusted accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's correct you have to create a public subnet (with route to igw)

Change aurora connectivity to public access

Adjust the security group to allow access only to the eks cluster

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aurora-private-public-endpoints/